# SharpZipLib and ziparchive open issue

Tags: vb.net, zip, php-ziparchive, sharpziplib

I'm creating a password protected zip file using SharpZipLib and inserting 3 files:

- Demo.xml
- Code.pdf
- File.htm

using the following code:

```
    Protected _file As ZipFile

    Public Sub New(ByVal pathName As String)
        If Not File.Exists(pathName) Then
            Try
                _file = ZipFile.Create(pathName)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                _file = New ZipFile(pathName)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Insert(ByVal name As String,
                      ByVal streamFile As Stream)

        Dim sds As New CustomStaticDataSource
        sds.SetStream(streamFile)          

        Try
            _file.BeginUpdate()
            _file.Add(sds, name)                
            _file.CommitUpdate()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Class CustomStaticDataSource
        Implements IStaticDataSource

        Private _stream As Stream
        Public Function GetSource() As Stream Implements IStaticDataSource.GetSource
            Return _stream
        End Function

        Public Sub SetStream(inputStream As Stream)
            _stream = inputStream
            _stream.Position = 0
        End Sub
    End Class
```

The file can be opened and unzipped with windows and 7zip.

When I try to open it and extract the first file from a C++ application on windows it fails regularly, I'm using [ziparchive](http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/Default.aspx).

Ziparchive detect it as corrupted by checking the consistence of crc, compressed and original size.

The issue is that the uncompressed size is not correctly detected, but always detected as hex 04034b50 (decimal 67324752).

Is there any option that must be set in order to fix this issue?

Comment: For the downvoter: the .NET code is present, but I can't add C++ code because of our policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue confirmed and fixed by ziparchive